# Activating a menu dynamically when some php condition is met

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, nav-pills

I want to trigger a tab to be active when some php conditions are met.

This is the bootstrap code I am using, it is a nav-pills and Toggable / Dynamic.

```css
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <h3>HOME</h3>
    <p>Some content.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h3>Menu 1</h3>
    <p>Some content in menu 1.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h3>Menu 2</h3>
    <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

By default Home tab is active. Before the page is loaded, I want to check if a global variable i.e `$_SESSION['variable1']` is set. If it is not set, then I should set menu2 to be active.

At the top of the code, I tried doing this and it didn't work

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['variable1'])){

echo " <script type=\"text/javascript\"> $('.nav-pills
a[href=\"#menu2\"]').tab('show') </script>";

}
```

But if I inspect element, and paste the JavaScript code above in the console, It work! I can't seem to be able to run it in my code though. Home tab stay active.

Comment: You can try to make sure that your JavaScript is executed after the dom is loaded. Echoing script tags conditionally is not the way to go if you want to make your front-end more dynamic. Have a look at angularJS.

Comment: Okay thanks, I'm having a look at angularJS. Never thought of that one, i meant never worked with angularJS.  :( .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are executing the script before the HTML is loaded.

I've tried it, and it works if you put the PHP code at the end of the `<body>`.

```
        ...
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
    if (!isset($_SESSION['variable1'])){

        echo " <script type=\"text/javascript\"> $('.nav-pills
        a[href=\"#menu2\"]').tab('show') </script>";

    }
    ?>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to just add the class using jquery?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  <?php 
     if (!isset($_SESSION['variable1'])){
  }?>
  $(".tab-pane").removeClass("active");
  $("#menu2").addClass("active");
<?php }
  ?>
});
</script>
```

hope this will work for you...

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to make it worked.

I did put it at the end of body. Was a stupid mistake I did.

Actually what happenend is the statement always return false.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['variable1'])){

echo " <script type=\"text/javascript\"> $('.nav-pills
a[href=\"#menu2\"]').tab('show') </script>";

}
```

And did not execute the code inside. Because the $_SESSION['variable1'] always has a value as I never cleared it out or destroyed it at some point. I had to use `session_detroy()` to initialize everything. And it works like a charm.

Thanks